# Why doesn't Scipy's curve_fit give the correct result for the following problem(s)?

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, scipy-optimize

Code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from numpy import *


def func(x, a, b): 
    return ff(x,a,b) 


ff= lambda x,a,b: eval("1/(a*x+b)")

xdata = [1 ,2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
ydata = [0.22, 0.1, 0.06, 0.04, 0.03, 0.024]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
print('\n', '[a b] for the best fit =    ', popt,'\n')
```

when this runs it gives

```
 [a b] for the best fit =     [ 4.62673137 -0.04794652]
```

Meanwhile according to my scientific calculator (or by solving this manually), the answer should be:

```
 [a b] for the best fit =     [ 0.9232 4.05396]
```

I tested the program repeatedly, this isn't the only example in which it doesn't provide correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked you calculations:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)
plt.scatter(xdata, func(np.array(xdata), 4.62673137, -0.04794652), c='r')
plt.scatter(xdata, func(np.array(xdata), 0.9232, 4.05396), c='g')
plt.show()
```

and found that `curve_fit()` gave good well-fitting parameters. The problem is with your other solution.

#### Suggestions:

Don't use `from X import *`. It makes code extremely hard to manage in some cases.

Don't use `eval()` if you don't need it. In this case:

```py
def func(x, a, b):
    return 1. / (a * x + b)
```

is shorter and clearer.

Comment: This is indeed strange, isn't fitting here done through the least squares method?
I linearized the function and then solved the matrix to get this solution, can't find any mistakes in my steps.

Comment: Also thank you for your suggestions, I'm aware of the second one, I just modified the code before posting it here ( it should be receiving an input, that's why I used it).

Comment: I'm guessing you're using your approximation beyond the range of validity. The plot shows that `curve_fit()` works correctly.

Comment: I agree that it gives a better fit, but I don't think that this is obtained from the least squares method, what puzzles me is that for most of the other tests I've done on it, we both agreed with our solutions.